# How can I prevent a program from checking my connection status

Tags: firewall, connection, blocking

I want to block a program from checking if my pc is actually connected to the internet.

I was blocking it's network connection with Windows Defender's Firewall.

In advanced Settings I simply added an outbound rule to block all three
connection types for main .exe file of the program.

It worked i mean it prevent the program from connecting, but it's not exactly what i wanted.

---

but the program was still trying to reach the internet.

I want the program to read my connection status as offline if it's possible

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Defender should be enough. Please show us what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tl;dr – you cannot.

---

Short of patching to modify the program's executable, you cannot `prevent a program from checking my connection status`.

It will execute its code, if you allow it to run. So, yes, technically, you can prevent it from checking your internet status by not allowing it run. Once it runs, it will do what it was programmed to do.

Others appear to be addressing “how do I prevent a program from accessing the internet”. If that is what you mean, then please edit the question’s title.

But, as the title stands, the answer is that you cannot.

Comment: If an application checking its connection status by accessing some network resource then obviously you can prevent it.

Comment: No you cannot - as the title stands. The OP is not asking how to prevent the app from ***knowing*** his connection status, but form ***querying*** it.

Comment: Well it's still theoretically possible to spoof the application into thinking that the network connection state is offline. Therefore it will not try to do the query. Although I wasn't able to find any implemented solution for this.

Comment: As the title stands, the question is ***NOT*** about what the application believes and how to spoof it. It is about preventing the application from making the query in the first place.

Comment: If the application will believe that the network connection is offline then it will not do the query therefore the goal will be achieved: the application was prevented from making the query.

Comment: The title says that the app is querying the ***connection status***. You start with "If the application will believe that the network connection is offline", but how can it "believe that the network connection is offline" is it does not "check the connection status"? But, we are splitting hairs over the English language here, to no real end. Unless the OP changes his title, I stand by my answer. And, given that he has accepted this answer, I doubt that he will do that.

Answer (score -2):

Try to detect which ports the program uses with the Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).